# NestJS microservice transport TCP vs gRPC

Tags: tcp, nestjs, microservices, grpc

I'm new to microservice. I am implementing request-response connections between NestJS applications using gRPC transport. Another option is the default TCP transport. gRPC is more modern but also more cumbersome to implement than TCP in typescript, which makes me think of switching to TCP.

But is the performance and microservice features of TCP compared to gRPC make it worth switching from gRPC to TCP?